# Regex that matches the same filename without the word inventory in doc files

Tags: regex

I have this filename that contains the same filename but only without the word inventory.
Now I want to get the match same filename without the word inventory on it. My problem is how can get the same filename using regex.

Here is my screenshot below.
[image]

Can someone help me figured this thing out?
I want to get the same filename of
front-AppealsCourtPI-Mar2021-inventory.doc
front-AppealsCourtPI-Mar2021.doc

Any help is muchly acppreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
/^front-AppealsCourtPI-Mar2021.*\.doc$/gm
```

`^`  asserts position at start of a line

`front-AppealsCourtPI-Mar2021` matches the characters front-AppealsCourtPI-Mar2021 literally (case sensitive)

`.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`\*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`\ .` matches the character . with index 4610 (2E16 or 568) literally (case sensitive)

`doc` matches the characters doc literally (case sensitive)

`$` asserts position at the end of a line